# Table with arrows and number on the arrows

Tags: tables, arrows

I want to create a table with four fields and arrows betweend those fields with numbers on it. What is the easiest way to that?

[image: Table with arrows]

Comment: this remind me more on picture than table ... what you try so far?

Comment: Please : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: @Zarko I want get a clue what approach would fit best for this problem. Since there are multiple ways to do it like for example with tikz.

Comment: @flav Please: specify

Comment: Give us a MWE ; Your post is just a "do it for me" ; Show us What you do so far.

Comment: @flav As already said I would like help in choosing the best suited method of achieving this, not a perfect copy & paste solution. The sketch is already a abstract version of what I want to do. Since approaches are different at the very base I would like to get help before I start.

Comment: In this case, I will use just node. You can also use matrix of node. What are  the point that you are questionning ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48498/discussion-between-indubio-and-flav).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As flaw said in his comment, this is "do-it-for-me" question ...

Anyway, I estimate, that the simple way is simple to draw your "table". With TikZ this is not so hard:

[image]

You can use `matrix` or `simple nodes` as I use for above image.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw=blue, very thick, minimum size=24mm, 
                 outer sep=0mm, font=\Large\bfseries},
every path/.style = {ultra thick,-Stealth, pos=0.7}
                        ]
\node (a) [box,label=A,label=left:A]    {AA};
\node (b) [box,right=of a,label=B]      {AB};
\node (c) [box,below=of a,label=left:A] {BA};
\node (d) [box,right=of c]              {BB};
%
\node[above=5mm of a.north east] {One Dimension};
\node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=-9mm] a.south west)  {Second Dimension};
%
\coordinate[below=5mm of a.north] (a1);
\coordinate[left =5mm of b.east]  (b1);
\coordinate[right=5mm of c.west]  (c1);
\coordinate[above=5mm of d.south] (d1);
%
\draw   (a1 -| b.north) edge ["\SI{2}{\%}"] (a1)
        (c1) edge ["\SI{2}{\%}" ']          (c1 |- a.west)
        (d1) edge ["\SI{2}{\%}"]            (d1 -| c.south)
        (b1 |- d.east) to ["\SI{3}{\%}"]    (b1);        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect example. Exactly the setup I want to use for my further work.